# How to get rid of root in Integral, without using Euler's substitution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Hey I am supposed to calculate this Integral,
$$\int \frac{3x+4}{\left ( x+1 \right )\left ( 4x+5 \right )\left ( 2x+3 \right )\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+1}}} dx$$

I do not know what to do with the squared root. Euler's substitution is not sufficient.

I was thinking about substitution, but I do not know, which terms exactly I should use.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would substitute $$t=\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+1}}$$ then we get
$$x=\frac{2-t^2}{t^2-1}$$
so $$dx=-2\,{\frac {t}{ \left( t-1 \right) ^{2} \left( t+1 \right) ^{2}}}dt$$
By the quotient rule we get
$$dx=\frac{-2t(t^2-1)-(2-t^2)2t}{(t^2-1)^2}dt$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94782/discussion-on-answer-by-dr-sonnhard-graubner-how-to-get-rid-of-root-in-integral).